# moss 2007 content db migration to sharepoint 2010

Tags: database, upgrade

I am in a middle of content database migration of MOSS 2007 built on SQLServer 2005 to SharePoint 2010 with SQLServer 2008 R2. This is what I've done.

1. Installed SP 2010 Standard Edition
2. Installed SQLServer 2008 R2 on another VM
3. Created Web Application with the same content database name of moss 2007 (SQLServer 2005) for eg "WSS_Content"
4. Went inside SQLServer and Deattached Content DB of SP2010
5. Restored moss 2007 content database backuped from SQLServer 2005 on SQLServer 2008 R2 (name was same after restoration -> WSS_Content"
6. applied the following command using Power Management Shell of SP2010
   `stsadm -o addcontentdb -url http://testserver:90 -databasename WSS_Content`

but I'm getting the following error.

**Sequence [Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence] cannot upgrade an object [SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content] whose build version [12.0.0.6219] is too old. Upgrade requires [12.0.0.6421] or higher**.

How do I solve this issue? Please note I didn't run Moss 2007 SP2 on my old intranet server...can this be a problem or I can move without it also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SP2 is [required](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263322.aspx) to be installed in the 2007 environment.  Steps are also provided on TechNet, [Perform a database attach upgrade](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303436.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the answer pirateeric...i am in a mess at this moment and need to perform this quickly so i am worried...when i will perform the database attach will my site collection with sub sites come as it is? we didnt do any customization and everything is out of the box.

Comment: Yes, everything should come over without too much trouble if it's minimally customized.  You have to make sure you have the prerequisites in place first.

Comment: so let me compile my jobs here which i need to do now.  1. Install SP2 on my MOSS 2007 portal ........2. Backup moss 2007 (2005) content database using 2005 management studio...restore the 2005 content db with SQLServer 2008 R2 instance (sp2010)....now run stsadm? am i correct ?

Comment: After you restore the database, you'll want to test it using the powershell test-spcontentdatabase command, then use the stsadm addcontentdatabase command or do it via powershell.  The process is detailed in the TechNet article.

Comment: thanks i will follow it tomorrow and will update my experience here..hopefully it will go smooth :)

Comment: Do a backup restore instead of a detach / attach, 'll keep security settings etc. intact

Comment: well finally i was able to migrate my site. The only mistake was that my moss 2007 has no SP2 installed. Went pretty smooth. Thanks alot for the help all of you.